# How to inspect the state object stored via window.history.pushState() in Chrome devtools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

> The state object is a JavaScript object which is associated with the
>   new history entry created by pushState().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

Is it possible to inspect the content of this state object with Chrome devtools?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `state` object is a property of the `history` object. You can access it in the Console with:

```
window.history.state
```

#### Example

[image: State Object]

### Log each time you pop off the history stack

#### Method 1:

```
var back = window.history.back;

window.history.back = function() {
    console.log("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + 
        JSON.stringify(window.history.state));

    return back.apply(this, arguments);
}

history.pushState({page: 1}, "title 1", "?page=1");
history.pushState({page: 2}, "title 2", "?page=2");
history.pushState({page: 3}, "title 3", "?page=3");
history.pushState({page: 4}, "title 4", "?page=4");
```

#### Method 2:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  console.log("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + 
      JSON.stringify(event.state));
};

history.pushState({page: 1}, "title 1", "?page=1");
history.pushState({page: 2}, "title 2", "?page=2");
history.pushState({page: 3}, "title 3", "?page=3");
history.pushState({page: 4}, "title 4", "?page=4");
```

This second one doesn't log the current state so you have to do that first.

[image: State]

It's not possible to peek through the history stack for security reasons.

Comment: can I easily see all the other states of the other history steps?

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek You can't see all the previous states in the stack for security reasons. You can write some code to log the state object to console every time you pop. See my updated answer.

Comment: That's why I have expected the stack to be accessible in the dev tools, not via JS in the console. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also have a look at the `popstate` [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event#examples).